# How to get twig to throw a notice on undefined var inside a template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am using Twig 1.28.2 and I have the following issue:

- in production mode (debug=false, strict_variables=false), twig just ignores undefined vars within templates.
- in devel mode, twig throws a `Twig_Error_Runtime` exception, which stops rendering of the page unless I catch the exception somewhere.

I would like to get a notice thrown just like PHP does with undefined php variables, so I could log those notices in both devel and production modes for analyzing later.

I could define an exception handler for `Twig_Error_Runtime`, but this type of exception is thrown in many other contexts, not only undefined vars. So it's probably not the best idea to catch this exception and continue executing code.

I looked into twig code, and it doesn't look very promissing:

```
    final protected function getContext($context, $item, $ignoreStrictCheck = false)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($item, $context)) {
            if ($ignoreStrictCheck || !$this->env->isStrictVariables()) {
                return;
            }

            throw new Twig_Error_Runtime(sprintf('Variable "%s" does not exist.', $item), -1, $this->getTemplateName());
        }

        return $context[$item];
    }
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Fix the problems, next time develop with `strict_variables=true`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Not possible, you would need to adjust the twig compiler

Comment: The question is an XY Problem, (you developed with the wrong/inverted settings false/false) now you want to do it correctly but want to fix the issues later, as if you want to bypass what the framework is telling you. Solution: fix the problems. `final` is there for a reason.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: I don't agree. I didn't develop with wrong settings, I just don't like the fact that undefined vars and indexes are completely ignored in production mode. A variable can depend on many other variables. It can be defined during development, but there are possible scenarios when it will become undefined in production. I want to log this kind of bugs / errors instead of relying on emails from users who see errors on the site.

Comment: My thoughts: if a variable depends on many other variables, your logic isn't right. Maybe your Twig template is too complex (never use Twig for business logic!)? A variable should not become undefined.